# Error connecting to database with mysql_i - Access Denied

Tags: php, mysql, access-denied

When I try to connect to the database I recieve this error :

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'eyohan01'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\artgallery\connect.php on line 7 Connection failed: Access denied for user 'eyohan01'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","")or die("we did not connect to the database");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"artgallery")or die("we did not select database");
?>
```

Comment: With respect, this is a case where careful reading of the error message should point you in the right direction. Either your username is not registered as a MySQL user or the password you provided is incorrect.

Comment: Have you read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-connecting.html ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied error with php xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876020/access-denied-error-with-php-xampp)