# Unable to connect from Intellij to mySql running in docker container - "specified database user/password combination is rejected"

Tags: mysql, docker, intellij-idea

Currently unable to connect from Intellij to mySql running locally on docker container on ubuntu.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| tasklogs           |
+--------------------+

+----------+-----------+------+
| DATABASE | HOST      | USER |
+----------+-----------+------+
| tasklogs | localhost | dev  |
| tasklogs | localhost | root |
+----------+-----------+------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dev@localhost                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dev`@`localhost`                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tasklogs`.* TO `dev`@`localhost` |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

docker ps -a:

[image]

When I connect via intellij:

[image]

i.e. **"The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28000][1045] Access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"**

I am putting in the right password.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you need to access your docker container via TCP, the "localhost" socket isn't in the docker container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @danblack mentioned, I needed to connect via tcp.

1) To get the IP of the container:

`docker inspect mysql1`

2) I changed the mysql user to allow access from all locations (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634084/are-users-user-and-userlocalhost-not-the-same)):

`'dev'@'%'` it was `'dev'@'localhost'` previously

That did the trick:

[image]

Comment: You can use on Linux `docker inspect mysqli | grep "IPAddress"` to get the ip address

Comment: Thank you! Connecting to the IP address of the container was key for my Postgres DB

Answer (score 6):

Solution

You didn't map your port with the localhost so you can't use localhost this is why couldn't do it

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Precisely my mistake!!! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 1):

**If none of the answers above worked for you:**

In my case I had forgotten to expose the port, but in addition I had mySQL running locally as well.

So in order to debug this I did the following:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root --password=password
```

The above was successful, and I managed to login through the terminal.

**Important note:** when the container was done, the same command allowed me to login to the local (non-containerized) mySQL. Thus I was trying to identify a potential conflict between the two, since both had the same port.

**Solution:** I exposed the DB in the container in a different port **3309** and thus managed to connect successfully.

```
ports:
  - "3309:3306"
```

*Also checking the following might help as well:*

- In the Advanced tab, add the following value to the enabledTLSProtocols setting ( Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70795115/4019835)):
  `enabledTLSProtocols: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3`
- Driver file: MySQL Connector/J ver 8.0.15

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Hurricane's response, I am attaching the screenshot of

`docker inspect yourContainerID` command

For me IP was: `172.17.0.2`

[image]

If you're using Linux(MacOS) you can also run
`docker inspect yourContainerID | grep "IPAddress"` to directly retrieve IPAddress

---

My problem was with volumes, so I created a `docker-compose.yml` file and run `docker compose up`

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  world_x:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'world_x'
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testsuperpass
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  mysql-volume:
```