# How to fix " [08S01] Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. "

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, wamp, intellij-datagrip

I'm working on a PHP project using PhpStorm + DataGrip + MySQL + WAMP and since then was working normally with remote database with these configurations (see images):

[image]

[image]

but suddenly I'm getting this error:

> [08S01] Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

[image]

Could someone knows what can I do to solve this error?

I already tried to do what I found here ([Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)) and that did not work yet.

I expect to connect again normally to my database.

Comment: If you roll back to 2019.1, does the data source still work? If so, it must be something related to the new SSH library we use. What exact 2019.2 build are you using?

Comment: What does "Test Connection" do for you? Is this an intermittent problem?

Comment: Guys thanks for contributions but i dicided to change  the way of the db communication, right now i'm using local db instead remote one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hi this error is because you are running a MySQL version 5 or 8.0 and later. And your server is configured to use the protocol of TLS 1.2. So, you need to enable TLS Protocols.

- Open Datagrip
- Go to Properties
- Data Sources > Advanced

In **enabledTLSProtocol** set the value:

```
TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

Test connection. And should work!

Comment: Things were working for me until they stopped. I think an upgrade to PyCharm removed my values for this param. Once I added your suggestion, everything worked again. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to set the value to TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 to get the connection to work.

Comment: I also had to set `useSSL` to false in order for this to work for me

Answer (score 2):

edit the JDBC url and append this query parameter `&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2`