# connecting to MYSQL in Docker with Intellij

Tags: mysql, docker, intellij-idea, docker-toolbox

I am just starting to do projects with the help of Docker (well Docker Toolbox not Docker Desktop). I have had some problems connecting with a mysql database running inside a container. Basically I cannot do it. I already changed from Localhost to 127.0.0.1 as can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozlwP.png) **This connection is made with the use of the IntelliJ GUI** hence the screenshots to make it easier to understand
This gave the error: The specified database user/password combination is rejected: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'User'@'192.168.99.1' (using password: YES)

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=WebShopDatabase
      - MYSQL_USER=User
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=Password
```

This container is up and running. I checked it with the docker ps, and afterwards the docker inspect docker_mysql_1: which showed the following:

```
[
{
    "Id": "847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6",
    "Created": "2020-05-23T19:17:21.33191426Z",
    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mysqld"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 18196,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2020-05-23T19:17:21.89238081Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:30f937e841c82981a9a6363f7f6f35ed6b9d5e3f16df50a72207e4a2a389983f",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6/847ef4819da9e29b5ce6d0102ef8175c20b6d0a277583721f4bb28ddc3d3c2f6-json.log",
    "Name": "/docker_mysql_1",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "673702fc973d8e1178ed0d791a7952fe49cf4f8f851149d0d0b9125d391e6390:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "docker_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "3306"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/271d75cd7adccad82d1f498bf979541eb98a7680b578868a1342227b68afd950-init/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/247631e3dcb755e0c6d06b98817d870d33afc3f0e56395589b635071f20ad7bc/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/14fa4bd9669e091e620e16d692556fa90c6cf483e046d34b6c2b6005eb5967a8/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/59b2da9f3817cbfafc7db9f9aa7ad66a07ce2078caf7d742eac74f0d38aa9ddb/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e05aec6f07c8db106fd4fa34d908af1b2c51fe7ee83b6a688038c4252dd1cb31/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f7b04fe4d47c0c4f6f4ae818b8758449ed5d1c67dfb41384a7c5778e18e0ccf2/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/df137f272a8499c320bc6fe053e3b3823d9966922a84f17fc5833b4ab117df8c/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8a1f20096ed32eb7a47ad598e2f211cd7c0581dbf6d4e12867dcb68d4a088f6c/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0a6304a0808d7bff98748b6893419d1e6b707bd8a8b0c4311c859eb7913ea21c/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d798769efed5fe7612b7fddbb29f155f576a3351b6a4e19b063d0147592e0a96/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/335fbab71322fc0bc7c4562f36ec985399ae8ab3fb3cc099326ab2dc9ec7c570/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8b563e8933ebf3a2a0656d54542cf8cc6624f3a3a38fecd8f734304e87d0c30e/diff:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf35e43c86791fd9332fcb49f99c03cc4fae513c1e73e87f46c670733aa64922/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/271d75cd7adccad82d1f498bf979541eb98a7680b578868a1342227b68afd950/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/271d75cd7adccad82d1f498bf979541eb98a7680b578868a1342227b68afd950/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/271d75cd7adccad82d1f498bf979541eb98a7680b578868a1342227b68afd950/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "673702fc973d8e1178ed0d791a7952fe49cf4f8f851149d0d0b9125d391e6390",
            "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/673702fc973d8e1178ed0d791a7952fe49cf4f8f851149d0d0b9125d391e6390/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "847ef4819da9",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {},
            "33060/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root",
            "MYSQL_DATABASE=WebShopDatabase",
            "MYSQL_USER=User",
            "MYSQL_PASSWORD=Password",
            "affinity:container==e139d12a2fab507df99eb64c707735b9fd002c90807c3129b5abaf790ae17dca",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
            "MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0",
            "MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.20-1debian10"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "Image": "mysql:8",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/lib/mysql": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "47a45119997895f95f6a3be2f1420dec2853da47cdad9b8bd363c36fdfa20c0d",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "mysql",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "223adce42cbcf45c72b4ca47f301cac3c5774e6cc809679f4f029fc664727283",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "3306"
                }
            ],
            "33060/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/223adce42cbc",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "docker_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "mysql",
                    "847ef4819da9"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "6cf406c0a4f20bc90d959131eead019d19a19c2c17aa054dad9843c470a21d6f",
                "EndpointID": "109e141ca8096fcf2350093183f657cf457e80afae04085087fb3c6fb5903d41",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which clearly contains the docker-compose.yml stated here above. The IP of the container is 172.18.0.2.

Since this did not work, I tried using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471608/unable-to-connect-from-intellij-to-mysql-running-in-docker-container-specifie). Which gave me the following 
[error see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db2vc.png). The IP of the docker container docker_mysql_1 (see screenshot all the way at the bottom and the output of the docker inspect just above) is 172.18.0.2. The error it gave was: [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.

Afterwards it was pointed out that I should connect to the Docker Toolbox IP which is 192.168.99.100. I did this in an hellowrold project (of which the screenshots are, but I now have the same errors and only changed the docker-compose.yml in the new project whilst copying every other class so nothing has changed except for the docker-copose.yml which I have given above), and now started another project (again of which I only changed the docker-compose.yml to what it is above, and copied all other classes) and have the following error for as well as the localhost as the 192.168.99.100 connection: [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. I checked if there were other containers running, there were none.

Comment: What's the actual commands you're running?  Does something literally print out `error see screenshot`, or can you replace this with the actual text of the error you're getting?  Are you correctly using the Docker Toolbox IP address (usually 192.168.99.100)?  (You will be unable to reach the container-private IP addresses from the host and it's not generally useful to look them up.)

Comment: The problem seems indeed to be the IP address. As you can see in the "error see screenshot", I use  172.18.0.2. However since I am using Docker Toolbox I need to go to that IP which is indeed 192.168.99.100. I now have a successful connection.

Comment: `error see screenshot` is not a description of a problem.  Please delete the two screenshot links and replace them with the text of the actual code you're running and the error message you're getting.  If you're directly using the container-private IP address, it won't work, but you haven't shown that detail one way or another in the question.

Comment: edited
although I do still think that it is easier to understand using the screenshots, than with the text since I use the IntelliJ GUI