# How to fix the issue: "The specified database user/password combination is rejected" using Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, database-connection, datasource

I'm using Spring application and stack is like: `Java 11`, `Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE`.

```
(technology versions may vary here)
```

When I try to connect to the database via `Data Source` using `Intellij IDEA`, I get always the issue like:

```
The specified database user/password combination is rejected:
[28P01] FATAL: password authentication failded for user 'postgres'
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

**To be noticed:** this answer is similar, but not related to:

[Unable to connect from Intellij to mySql running in docker container - "specified database user/password combination is rejected"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54471608/8370915)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To fix it**:

you need to check your `application.properties` file and change the value of `user password` on line:

```
spring.datasource.password=your_password
```

**The cause of issue is:**

your value of the property `spring.datasource.password` in `application.properties`

does not match the user password what was selected by default during installing your database system.

E.g. more specifically on the step ["Enter the password for the database superuser (postgres)"](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/):

[image]

**To clarify:** provided example is for `PostgreSQL`, but it can be another `database system`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this assumes you run Linux

if the other answer provided by invzbl3 doesn't work, check out this solution, it worked for me. Make sure to restart afterwards.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/postgresql/#_initial_configuration

> If you’re getting ident errors from your app you’ll probably need to perform the accepted solution described at https://serverfault.com/questions/406606/postgres-error-message-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user?newreg=a4fdc3e21349449985cc65b82399c5b4

(if you don't have nano, just use any other text editor)

> `sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`
> and edit host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident to host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5.

> This should allow most applications to connect with username/password.