# what is the meaning of "%" between when you create user and giving grant in mysql

Tags: mysql

So basically what is the difference of '%' and 'localhost' when you create a user and give a grant to the created user.

what will happens when you create/grant a user with 'localhost' and '%' each

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
vs
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
vs
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

it seems like if I create a user with 'localhost' it means I can only log in the user in the local server, not from remote. and in terms of the grant with 'localhost', is that mean that the user only can access to database from local server, not from remote, is that correct?

Comment: thanks but I know what % means. I just want to know the comparison of '%' and 'localhost' on creating a user and giving a grant

Comment: I changed the question a bit. can you check? @pnorton

Comment: Hi Byeonggil How do you read CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; ? have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, those are working fine. I want to know the accessibility depending on 'localhost' and '%' from the remote when I create a user and grant the user. it might be a silly question but it just from curiosity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634084/are-users-user-and-userlocalhost-not-the-same

Comment: Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html  ... dances around the question that was asked. In MySQL, the two statements create two separate and distinct users, each with their own password and privileges.  (`@'localhost'` is for connecting with Unix socket only. The `@'%'` allows connection from any IP address...

Comment: thank you, bill, spencer, pnorton. those helped a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL treats '%' as a wildcard matching any client who connects via TCP. So any hostname or any IP address, including 127.0.0.1

MySQL treats 'localhost' as a special case. It only matches a client who connects only via the UNIX socket. The UNIX socket is faster than TCP, but it only works locally.

If you want to create a user who can connect either from any host via TCP, or via the UNIX socket, you must actually create two users. It's up to you to give them the same passwords and grant them the same privileges. MySQL does not ensure that.

Comment: My coworker found a weird case to make this even more confusing. The Go connector for MySQL resolves "localhost" to its IP address 127.0.0.1 before connecting. So it forces you to use TCP. Every other MySQL client library allows "localhost" to mean the UNIX socket.