# Problems with MySql and Server

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a database into my server (not localhost) and when i'm trying to put a few data inside my database using a php file, it shows two warnings: 'A link to the server could not be established' and 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)' .

I did many things to make it right, but nothing worked =(

Here's a little bit of code:

```
  <?php

define('DB_USER',"X"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',"X");
define('DB_DATABASE',"X");
define('DB_SERVER',"www.X.com.br");

?>
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()); 

require_once __DIR__. '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$query = "SELECT *FROM carteira";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Post your PHP code being used to connect to the database (X out the password and username of course).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not connecting to your database properly. First make sure you are actually connected to your database before you try and edit things in your tables.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// some code

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This code will try and connect and if it doesn't it will let you know you did not connect.

If you know your connection details are correct and you still cannot connect it may because there is a remote access permission error. Assuming your connecting to a new remote database and your work is not also hosted with that partner; Which means your host server does not like remote requests which means you need to go to your user panel and add your IP address to the exceptions access list to grant you access to your database remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be self explanatory, you should probably install everything again, or check this  [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%27t%20connect%20to%20MySQL%20server%20on%20%27localhost%27%20%2810061%29&rlz=1C1AFAB_enAE449AE449&oq=Can%27t%20connect%20to%20MySQL%20server%20on%20%27localhost%27%20%2810061%29&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for more of the same

Answer (score 0):

you should post some code :) maybe you just didn't connect to the right server. Maybe some firewall is between you and the server not allowing you to connect.
As you stated yourself:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Your script connects to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MySQL server is running (mysql process and probably service started):

Windows often't isn't set up to map the local loopback address, 127.0.0.1 (which MySQL binds on) to localhost.

Try '127.0.0.1' instead.

See: [MySQL working with 127.0.0.1 but not working with localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283746/mysql-working-with-127-0-0-1-but-not-working-with-localhost)